# read excl file to nestjs using excljs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I am trying to process excl file into nestjs app

```
import ExcelJS from 'exceljs';
.
.
.
async import(file) {
    const workBook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
    const data = await workBook.xlsx.load(file);
}
```

and I got that error
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Workbook')`

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake in importing, it should be like

`import * as ExcelJS from "exceljs";`